# Как в 1С:Управление Торговлей 8, ред.11 отредактировать остатки товаров на складе?

Tags: 1с

Добрый день, всем! Буду краток в своем изложении:
как в 1С:Управление Торговлей 8, ред.11 отредактировать остатки товаров на складе?

Акцентирую на слове ОТРЕДАКТИРОВАТЬ, а не посмотреть.

P.S. 1с не люблю и плохо разбираюсь в нем =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Только править старые документы или через [инвентаризацию](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aknLChzmSkw)

Comment: Есть документ "Корректировка записей регистров".

Answer (score 1):

Кратко, остатки хранятся в регистрах, регистры двигают документы => Надо править документы, либо вводить корректировочные документы.